# Minimum Volume Enclosing Ellipsoids

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, simplex, polytopes

suppose we have a simplex in $R^{n}$. the vertices of this simplex is permuted a point in $R^{n}$. for example in $R^{3}$, the vertices are $(a,b,c)$ , $(c,a,b)$, $(b,c,a)$. and we know that there are linearly independent so form a simplex.

my question is that what is the equation of the ellipsoid  which contains described simplex and which has minimal volume with this property.

Comment: $R^{3}$ simplex has 4 points.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the poster is describing an $n-1$ dimensional simplex in $R^{n}$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers then why would enclosing elipsoid have any volume?

Comment: It's a degenerate problem as discussed in my answer- you can either project down to n-1 dimensions or you can make the set full dimensional in some way.

Comment: https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/sdo.html#minimal-enclosing-ellipsoid

Comment: See <https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf>.

Answer (score 3):

Finding the minimum volume ellipsoid for a set of $m$ points in $R^{n}$ is a problem that has been extensively studied.  There isn't a closed form formula, but rather optimization algorithms are used to find a minimum volume ellipsoid.  See the recent book

Michael J. Todd,  *[Minimum-Volume Ellipsoids: Theory and Algorithms](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611974386)*, SIAM 2016.

Todd's book includes MATLAB codes to implement the methods discussed in the book.

In your case, the $n$ points lie in an $n-1$ dimensional hyperplane in $R^{n}$, so the minimum volume ellipsoid is not actually attained as a full $n$-dimensional ellipsoid.   You can create arbitrarily thin (in the direction perpendicular to the hyperplane) ellipsoids around the points with volumes that approach 0.   In this degenerate case, there are a couple of things that you could do:

if you want a full $n$-dimensional ellipsoid in the original space, simply add a point to make the set full-dimensional by taking the average of the $n$ points and then adding a small displacement orthogonal to the hyperplane to get a point outside of the hyperplane.

You could also reduce the dimension of the problem by 1 and find a minimum volume $n-1$ dimensional ellipsoid in the $n-1$ dimensional hyperplane defined by the points.

To do this, start with points $x^{(1)}$, $\ldots$, $x^{(n)}$, and define $n-1$ vectors

$y^{(i)}=x^{(i)}-x^{(n)},\;\; i=1, 2, \ldots, n-1$.

Then any vector $z$ in the hyperplane defined by the $n$ points can be written as

$z=x^{(n)}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \alpha_{i} y^{(i)}$

Using your favorite orthogonalization method (something better than Gram-Schmidt!) construct an orthonormal basis for the $y^{(i)}$ vectors,

$w^{(1)}, w^{(2)}, \ldots, w^{(n-1)}$

Now, any point $z$ in the hyperplane can be expressed as

$z=x^{(n)}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \beta_{i} w^{(i)}$

The coordinate transformation $y^{(j)} \rightarrow \beta^{(j)}$ then gives you a set of $n-1$ vectors in $R^{n-1}$.  Add the $0$ vector to this set to represent the base point $x^{(n)}$.  Now, find an $n-1$ dimensional ellipsoid of minimum volume enclosing the $n$ points

$0, \beta^{(1)}, \beta^{(2)}, \ldots, \beta^{(n-1)}$.

Comment: how I can do that? I meant how I can find this ellipsoid in n-1 dim?

Comment: See updated answer.  You've still got to do the optimization to find a minimum volume enclosing ellipsoid.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I don't think he really has since there are very few points. They all will lie on the ellipsoid itself.

Comment: I agree that all of the points will end up on the ellipsoid, but it's not immediately obvious to me how you'd find the center point and matrix defining the interpolating ellipsoid using that information- you'd have a nonlinear system of equations to solve.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Could you elaborate on the convergence of Khachiyan's algorithm for the MVEE when the points are nearly degenerate? By this I mean that I have 4 points in 3 dimensional space that almost lie on a 2 dimensional plane (i.e. a small distance off-plane).

Comment: Khachian's ellipsoid algorithm is seldom a good choice due to numerical instability.  Applying an SDP solver to the SDP formulation of the MVEE problem is probably the most reasonable thing to do in practice.